# Didn't find apache spark service in data and analytics section of bluemix

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

Has bluemix removed apache spark service from its services ? I want to create one but did not find it in Data and Analytics section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache Spark service is still present in Bluemix and in that section. Here is the direct link to the [Apache Spark service](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/apache-spark/).

Comment: Found this service in US Region, and not in GB.

Comment: That's correct, here is a good overview of what to find where: http://mycatalog.mybluemix.net/